# Url helper's invisible inside the layout. ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url, extension-methods, helper

I was looking at the [article](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/aspnet-mvc-url-extensions?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+zones%2Fdotnet+%28.NET+Zone%29) on `Url` helpers extension methods. And I tried to follow the article but as result none of written extension methods were visible in the layout (shared *.chtml file).

```
public static class UrlHelperExtensions
{
    public static String Image(this System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper helper, String fileName)  
    {             
         return helper.Content("~/Content/Images/" + fileName);  
    }
    public static String Stylesheet(this System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper helper, String fileName)
    {
        return helper.Content("~/Content/Stylesheets/" + fileName);
    }
    public static String Script(this System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper helper, String fileName)
    {
        return helper.Content("~/Content/Scripts/" + fileName);
    }
}

// inside the layout I tried to use this:
<link href="@Url.Content("Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

How do I make `Url` extension methods visible inside the layout?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code showing what you tried?

Comment: Your sample code is calling `Url.Content` in the layout file.  What happens when you replace this with `Url.Stylesheet()`?  What name space is your `UrlExtensions` class in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you have a reference to your namespace where you are using the helpers.

So if you created the class `UrlExtensions`  in `MyClassLib.Web`, add `@using MyClassLib.Web` to the top of your .cshtml file.